# Installing Chrome on old version of Mint

Tags: google-chrome, linux-mint

I'm trying to install Chrome on Linux Mint 14 (nadia) and am getting the following errors:

```
google-chrome-stable : 
Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.17.2) but 3.15.4-0ubuntu0.12.10.2 is to be installed
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.8.0) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1) but 4.0-0ubuntu26.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm guessing - and it is a guess - that the repositories for my version of mint don't have the latest versions of the required libraries. To cut a long story short I ended up uninstalling my existing version of Chrome (42.x) and am now stuck.

Is there anyway around this and getting a compatible version of Chrome running other than upgrading mint (now's a bad time to do that for me)?

Very grateful for any advice here.

Comment: See if there's a portable version of Chrome, which would be self-contained.  If so, that would be a temporary solution (you could load it onto your system, create a link, and use it like installed software).

Comment: Isn't there a version of Chrome or Chromium in your repositories? If not, look in the Ubuntu or Debian repositories.

Comment: It seems like the repository is picking up the latest version of chrome, so I wonder if my repositories are pointing to the wrong place?

Comment: I apparently have v53 (default)  and v42 in the repository.  If trying to Force version 42 I get errors `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Unable to lock the download directory.`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` and see if you can install it after that. 
If not try using `sudo aptitude install chromium` to get chromium installed. Aptitude is better at handling broken packages.

Finally try `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then try to install chromium.